# How to make HTTPS for only private asp.net pages?

Tags: security, https

I Have login page on my asp.net page and I need this page to open and appear like that

old url (http://www.example.com/login.aspx)

and I want it like that

new url (**https**://www.example.com/login.aspx)

how to change the http to be https only for the login.aspx page

I'm using vb.net with asp.net under visual studio 2008.

I need any help please.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) to make sure that if you go to the login page on HTTP it will automatically redirect to HTTPS, and if it isn't the login page, redirect them to HTTP.

Comment: I already made the redirecting to the https but i think it needs SSL and I don't know to put ssl for this page.

Comment: You need to setup IIS to support it, which is an entirely different question. A little searching on the Internet will provide a lot of resources for you. If you are trying to get it working in a development environment, you'll need to switch to IIS instead of the built in sever (Cassini) since it doesn't expose SSL functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the response on the Http page and make sure all your links go to the secure page?

Comment: Here is an example I found that shows how to do it: http://www.leastprivilege.com/PartiallySSLSecuredWebAppsWithASPNET.aspx.